# Ascii encoding Ubuntu

Tags: java, php, bash, apache, utf-8

I have an Apache server with a PHP page. In my program I upload to the PHP page a file which will be managed by a bash script. Basically the script invokes a jar which performs some computations among which printing a list of characters in utf-8 encoding. A thing that puzzles me is the fact that if I call the script as root (my user does not belong to the www-data group), I can see the list of non-ASCII characters (e.g.  ¼, ½, ¾, ¿, À, Á, Â, Ã), instead when I upload the file via the curl command, after the ASCII characters I receive only '?' in the response. I've also tried to print everything in a file from the jar, but still in the second case the non-ASCII characters are not printed out.
Why does this happen? Is that a problem of the user www-data?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In what this question is related to java?

Comment: The program that produces the output is written in java

Comment: if you want those characters to reach your server through any http conformant client such as curl, you need to "hex-encode" those characters, otherwise the client won't send them to the server.

Comment: @ezra-s is not the client to send them, but the server that executes the script. Moreover, also if I output them in a file on the server, the result does not change, in the first case I see the characters, in the second one I see question marks.

Comment: @AntonioLaMarra my fault, I read too quickly :(